# Spot commands in the layout file

Tags: macros, page-breaking, marginpar

I'm searching for a way to highlight some commands in the layout file. I need, in my proofreading work (I'm a typesetter) to quickly spot some kinds of commands like vertical space modifiers or page breaking commands.

I'm testing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

\let\Oldenlargethispage\enlargethispage
\renewcommand{\enlargethispage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{ETP}}\Oldenlargethispage}

\let\Oldpagebreak\pagebreak
\renewcommand{\pagebreak}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{pagebreak}}\Oldpagebreak}

\let\Oldclearpage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{clearpage}}\Oldclearpage}

\let\Oldnewpage\newpage
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{newpage}}\Oldnewpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\pagebreak

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But, in a second time I'll save, for example, the following code:

```
\let\Oldenlargethispage\enlargethispage
\renewcommand{\enlargethispage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{ETP}}\Oldenlargethispage}

\let\Oldpagebreak\pagebreak
\renewcommand{\pagebreak}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{pagebreak}}\Oldpagebreak}

\let\Oldclearpage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{clearpage}}\Oldclearpage}

\let\Oldnewpage\newpage
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\marginpar{\colorbox{red}{newpage}}\Oldnewpage}
```

in a separate file (e.g. `pagebreaks-highlight.tex`) and I will compile with (an alias of):

```
latex -src-specials -synctex=1 "\AtBeginDocument{\input{\string~/path/pagebreaks-highlight.tex}} \nonstopmode\input{myfile.tex}"
```

to quicky spot my targets commands **without changing my working file**.

My question is: what's the best way to highlight this kind of commands **without changing the overall layout**? I suspect that `\marginpar` may introduce layout changes.

I'like something like the `showkeys` package layout but "colored".

[image]

Comment: Any `\marginpar` may modify the page/line breaks. Not relevant, but are you sure about `-src-specials`? It's an obsolete feature.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the "special commands" rendered into the output? wouldn't i be better so "prove read" that in an editor like TexStudio, where you could apply additional highlighting on top of the default?

Comment: @egreg I wasn't aware that `-src-specials` is obsolete. I use it to achieve forward-search in okular/emacs. It works fine.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, I need absolutely to have emacs as my text editor because of the tons of tools I built...

Comment: I strongly believe that the highlighting is better done in emacs then in the resulting PDF ...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I know, but in some cases it's really quicker and easier (for my purposes) have this kind of macro rendered in the layout file. Expecially in the final check of the document.